# How to have row numbers with respect to a value in a group

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I have my data as follows:

```
Pagetype    member_id    created_at    rownum    
   A            2          date          1            
   B            2          date          2             
   C            2          date          3             
   D            4          date          1            
   B            4          date          2             
   R            4          date          3             
   B            13         date          1             
   S            13         date          2             
   B            13         date          3
```

And I would like to add another column to it as follows:

```
Pagetype    member_id    created_at    rownum    DesiredRownum
   A            2          date          1            -1
   B            2          date          2             0
   C            2          date          3             1
   D            4          date          1            -1
   B            4          date          2             0
   R            4          date          3             1
   B            13         date          1             0
   S            13         date          2             1
   B            13         date          3             2
```

I would like to assign the value 0 to this `DesiredColumn` whenever `PageType` is B for a given `member_id`. Any values of `PageType` before B for any `member_id` should be assigned negative values, and any values of `PageType` after B for any `member_id` should be asigned increasing positive values.

The query I used to get my data is as follows:

```
select pagetype,
member_id,
created_at,
row_number() over(partition by member_id order by created_at)
from table
order by member_id,
created_at
```

How do I add this new column to my data?

**EDIT:** Slight change. The `PageType` can repeat for any given user. For example, the `PageType` B repeats for `member_id` 13. In this case, we would want to calculate values wrt the first occurence of B.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After calculating the row numbers, you can get the value for "B" and use that for the calculation:

```
select t.*,
       (seqnum -
        max(case when pagetype = 'B' then seqnum end) over (partition by member_id)
       ) as b_diff
from (select pagetype, member_id, created_at,
             row_number() over (partition by member_id order by created_at) as seqnum
      from table
     ) t
order by member_id, created_at
```

Comment: I just made a slight change to the question.

Comment: You should ask another question.